# How to alert() when location.reload() if finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to show a simple popup using alert() , however, only after the page is reloaded fully.

Right now, the popup, is displayed and disappears after a second or even less because the code is executed at the same time.

My code in the ajax success:

```
success : function( response ) {
    location.reload(); 
    alert(response);
}
```

How to make the code to be executed one after another and not at the same time?

Comment: Basically, you can't, `location.reload` just refresh the page. Do the alert before ...

Comment: what about async: false as suggested by the user below?

Comment: wow, why so many downvotes? Just because it cannot be done?

Comment: Actually, nothing can be done after a `location.reload()`, why don't you alert before?

Comment: what about using something else instead of reload() e.g. href?

Comment: I assume the downvotes are because you haven't explained why you can't use the obvious solution (alert before reloading the page). Now it looks like you're trying to force a solution that may or may not be reasonable for the actual problem.

Comment: Well, I can implement a php code that will check sessions, and save stuff into session then reload , but I wanted something simple and JS cannot help. but I will do it via a workaround.

Comment: You're still not answering the question (why not do it before the reload), so I suppose you'll have to do it the hard way then.

Comment: @Juhana I have find the solution. It can be done in JS with localStorage. More here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: That's good for you, although for some reason you're still refusing to clarify the original intent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you reload the page, basically the JavaScript will essentially "reset", so nothing after the reload() call will continue to run. You may need to consider placing a variable in localStorage, and doing your alert on document.ready.

Here would be an example. Let's say that you want to refresh the page after the user clicked a particular button.

```
$(".myButton").on("click", function(){
     localStorage.setItem("buttonClicked", true); 
     location.reload(); 
}); 

$(document).ready(function(){
// This function will run on every page reload, but the alert will only 
// happen on if the buttonClicked variable in localStorage == true
    if(localStorage.getItem("buttonClicked");               
        alert("you clicked the button!") 
    }
});
```

Comment: Finally! This works great! However I had to add `localStorage.removeItem("buttonClicked");` before the alert, other wise it will show the alert on ever reload and not only once.